# How to write functions sequentially in JavaScript/typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have problems in the following funcitons' orders, sometimes fun2() perform before fun1().

What I would like is writing the functions in order.

This my code:

```
const fun1 = () => new Promise(resolve => {
      db.run(
        'INSERT INTO header (name,email) VALUES ("' +
          name +
          '","' +
          email +
          '")',
        function(err, row) {
          if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
          }
          console.log('Entry Added');
          resolve('Inserted into header');
        }
      );
    });

const fun2 =  () => new Promise(resolve => {
      let sql = `SELECT id FROM header ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;`;
      db.all(
        `SELECT id FROM header ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;`,
        [],
        (err, rows) => {
          if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
          }
          rows.forEach(row => {
            resolve(row['id']);
          });
        }
      );
    });


fun1().then(fun2).then(messages => console.log(messages));
```

It showing me this error `filename.tsx:389 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: fun1.then is not a function`

Comment: Instead of `return console.error(err);`, you should `reject` the promise.

Comment: `rows.forEach(row => {
            resolve(row['id']);
          });` doesn't work if there are no rows or multiple rows. Instead, call `resolve` once and pass an array.

Answer (score 0):

`fun1` and `fun2` should be functions that return Promises. That way, the Promises are instantiated when calling the corresponding function

Answer (score 0):

`fun1` and `fun2` aren't functions, they're promises, and they both kick off the moment you say `new Promise(...)`.

If you want to run them in sequence, make them functions:

```js
// functions that return promises
const fun1 = () => new Promise( ... )
const fun2 = () => new Promise( ... )

fun1().then(fun2).then(messages => console.log(messages));
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've edited the question, but it gave me a new error when I tried your way.

Comment: The code in your question doesn't show this, but the error indicates you're not including the parentheses on `fun1()`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original). It will do a lot of heavy lifting for you. As it turns out, it is actually tricky to turn callback functions into proper promises.

```js
const util = require('util');
const db = require('some/sql/package'); 

const query = util.promisify(db.all)

// then either
query('some sql expression')
    .then((data1) => {
      console.log(data1)
      return query('other statement')
    })
    .then((data2) => console.log(data2))
    .catch(console.warn);

// or 
(async () => {
  data1 = await query('some sql expression')
  data2 = await query('other statement')
})().catch(console.warn)
```

note that you MUST have a semicolon on the line before when using the iife like that.